# get value in JSON iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I have this json data:

```
{
"aviao": [
{
  "ID": "1",
  "NOME": "ART580",
  "LOGO": null,
  "NOMECOMPAINHA": "TACV",
  "CAPACIDADE": "250",
  "DATE_LOG": "2013-12-10 17:02:34",
  "vooses": [
    {
      "ID": "1",
      "CODIGO": "V534PS",
      "ID_ROTA": "1",
      "ID_AVIAO": "1",
      "AEROPORTOPARTIDA": "1",
      "AEROPORTOCHEGADA": "2",
      "DATAPARTIDA": "2013-08-08",
      "DATACHEGADA": "2013-08-09",
      "HORAPARTIDA": "23:45:00",
      "HORACHEGADA": "02:20:00",
      "TIPOVOO": "Nacional",
      "ESTADO": "0",
      "DATE_LOG": "2013-12-10 17:02:47"
    },
    {
```

see that in the vooses attribute I have other attributes but I don't know how to get them.

Can anyone help please?

Comment: Show your relevant code. What have you tried so far?

Comment: First go to json.org and learn the JSON syntax.  It only takes 5-10 minutess to learn.  Then study the iOS documentation for NSDictionary and NSArray.  Then find some tutorials or examples and study them.  Then attempt to write something come back to us if you have problems with what you've written.  JSON is only difficult because people try to use it without bothering to understand what they're doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
NSDictionary *jsonDict; // Your current dict from your json.
NSArray *aviaos = [jsonDict valueForKey:@"aviao"]; // This array has a dictionary. Or maybe more
NSDictionary *dictionary = [aviaos firstObject];
NSArray *vooses = [dictionary valueForKey:@"vooses"];
// Vooses is an array of dictionaries
for (NSDictionary *dict in vooses)
{
    // You don`t know keys:first ask for them
    NSArray *keysInDictObject = [dict allKeys];
    for (NSString *key in keysInDictObject)
    {
        NSLog(@"Do you want with this key %@",key);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot...just what i needed! In this case it catch just the first object and if i want it to catch form a index (i). how it should be??

Answer (score 1):

You need to iterate over this array and get each value out for himself.

```
var myArray = yourJSON from "vooses" as NSArray

func myStuff (myCollection) {
    for item in myCollection {
    ID = myCollection["ID"] as NSString (assuming a String here)
    CODIGO = myCollection["CODIGO"] as NSString
    ...
    ...

var singleVooses:Object = Object()
singleVooses.ID = ID
singleVooses.CODIGO = CODIGO
...
...


myObjects.append(singleVooses)
}
```

call this method wherever you want, and then you can use your myObjects Array to fill in a TableView or something else

Comment: This is more of a comment than a useful answer. Provide more detail and show some code to make this a good answer.

Comment: The question is tagged Objective-C. Answers should be in Objective-C.

Answer (score 0):

Just keep in mind the following:

1. An object(`{}`) is the equivalent to `NSDictionary`
2. An Array(`[]`) is the equivalent to `NSArray`

Once you know that It's very easy to parse any `JSON` structure.

**example:**

```
NSArray *aviao = json[@"aviao"];//note json is NSDictionary
NSArray *vooses = aviao[0]["vooses"];

for (NSDictionary *voose in vooses)
{
    NSLog(@"Voose ID = %@",voose["ID"]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your json data is contained in an NSString (`originalJsonString`), parse it into an NSArray like this:

```
// Convert json string to an array
NSData * jsonData = [originalJsonString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
NSError * error=nil;
NSArray *parsedJson=nil;
if (jsonData)
{
    parsedJson = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:jsonData options:0 error:&error];
}

if (!error && parsedJson)
{
    // Use your new array
}
```